# Convert string from file to ASCII and binary

Tags: java, binary, ascii

Say I open a text file like this:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String file_name = "file.txt";

    try {
        Read file = new ReadFile(file_name);
        String[] Lines = file.openFile();

        for (int i = 0; i < es.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(Lines[i]);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Now, I want to change the result to binary (for further conversion into AMI coding), and I suppose that firstly I should turn it to ASCII (though I'm also not 100% certain if that's absolutely necessary), but I'm not sure if I should better change it to chars, or perhaps is there an easier way?

Please, mind that I'm just a beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you happen to know for sure that the files will be ASCII encoded? Assuming it is, you can just use the getBytes() function of string:

```
byte[] lineDefault = line.getBytes();
```

There is a second option for .getBytes() as well if you don't want to use the default encoding. I often am using:

```
byte[] lineUtf8 = line.getBytes("UTF-8");
```

which gives byte sequences which are equivalent to ASCII for characters whose hex values are less than 0x80.

Comment: Very good point about the encoding. On the other hand, the file could be treated as binary; Then only the file sender and the receiver would need to agree on the encoding.

Comment: Yeah, that was why I was asking about the file being encoded that way. But I guess if you want to separate on new lines, you need to comprehend the file in an encoded fashion.